# how to improve clustering performance

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, k-means

> I have a dataset with 930 users and 1630 movies.Each movie is represented by 19 features. Iam using K-means clustering to cluster similar movies.When no of clusters=2,algorithm gives the best performance.I still need to improve  efficiency of the algorithm.What are the best possible ways to do so?

Comment: please share an example of your data with the expected output.

Comment: user data example:(user_id,age,gender,random number)  
                               1|24|M|technician|85711
                                  2|53|F|other|94043
                                3|23|M|writer|32067
                               4|24|M|technician|43537                               
movie data example:(movie_id,movie,release year,features of the movie)

Comment: features of movie:( unknown | Action | Adventure | Animation |
              Children's | Comedy | Crime | Documentary | Drama | Fantasy |
              Film-Noir | Horror | Musical | Mystery | Romance | Sci-Fi |
              Thriller | War | Western |)                                                     example movie data:                                                                                   1,(0|0|0|1|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0)
2,(0|1|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0)
3,(0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|1|0|0)

Comment: requirement:  mean squared error should be <1.08 and as least as possible